# Create a path with user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to put together a path that works with user input:

```
a=input("Select a Path name to Navigate: ")
b=input("Select a second Path name to Navigate: ")
    subprocess.Popen((r'explorer /open,"\\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\a\Test\test\b\test"'))
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to do it. I either just get errors or it opens Windows Explorer without considering the path.

the path has 11 directories and 4 of them must be specified by the user via input

I'm really looking forward to your help for get this.

regards
Sebastian

Comment: you need to use an f-string `f"\\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\{a}\Test\test\{b}\test"` notice the f before quotes and the curly brackets around your variables

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thank you for the quick answer. I’ll try it tomorrow, when I’m back to work.  Best regards

Comment: you can also use `os.path.join()` to be unambiguous about joining paths.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I’ve tryed it at home, but I got a error from Windows.. fc files can’t read by widows

Comment: @D.L ive tryed this but with is.path I don’t get access to the network server. Only per subprocess

Comment: `os.path.join()` creates a string for the path that you ultimately want to get to. because it is a string, you can copy its value and make sure that it is the path that you want. I have tested it on `windows10` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on `windows10`:

```
import os
import subprocess

a=input("Select a Path name to Navigate: ")
b=input("Select a second Path name to Navigate: ")
path = os.path.join(a, b)

print('opening', path)

subprocess.Popen((f'explorer /open,{path}'))
```

In my case (`windows10`) a and b were `c:\` and `folder_name`

You can extend this to as many folders as you like.
`path = os.path.join(a, b, c, d etc...)`

Comment: I should point out that you need to be careful with the drive letters and missing a `:` or `\` will ruin the code. So you could at this point check if the directory exists.

Comment: Hello @D.L, so i got The System can not found the data.  The files are on a NAS Network not local on my PC. I`ve only read permits regards

Comment: @INegativeI,  okay, then this suggests to that there this is a path or access issue and *not* a code issue. You might need to open a separate question as this part of your problem is resolved. In your case, probably include the `nas network` path...

Comment: @ D.L ive tryed it with this code:  mypath="\\NAS\\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder" path= os.path.join(mypath)  f=open(os.path("path")) but this also not work.     Answer from Python: Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'path'

Comment: it work now. by mypath="\\NAS\\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder" we need \\\\ not \\ thank you.

Comment: @INegativeI  I am glad to have helped. Please upvote and accept the answer given that it resolved the problem. Other users might find this helpful.